# WebDriveManager jar is not recognizable in Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

Configured needed dependency from here in pom.xml: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

But still having an error when declaring WebDriverManager.

[image: WebDriverManager error]

Comment: Where is your `import ...WebDriverManager`?

Comment: Exactly, I don't know why it's not importing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are declaring WebDriverManager as a test dependency but then you are using in the regular source folder. To solve it, simple remove `<scope>test</scope>` from the WebDriverManager declaration in your pom.xml and try again.